# I am fasting for 40 days

Tags: catholicism, christian-living, fasting

I am fasting for 40 days I was wondering if I can stop fasting every Sunday and eat normal food my mom said I can but I want to be sure

Comment: StackExchange is a little different than a typical Q&A. I would consider rewording your question to something like, "According to Roman Catholicism, is it acceptable during Lent to not fast on Sundays?"

Comment: Might I suggest, some fasting but don't go off the deep end, as much prayer as you like, it won't hurt you, and Alms giving, if you are young, you could give your time rather than money.

Comment: I knew this was asked somewhere before, I guess it was me who asked it!  There's also this question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27461/questions-about-lent which I think probably is a little broad

Comment: Try eating one meal a day at 3 PM ("the ninth hour"), which St. Thomas Aquinas argues is a good Lenten practice in [_Summa Theologica_ II-II q. 147 a. 7 ("Whether the ninth hour is suitably fixed for the faster's meal?")](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS147.html#SSQ147A7THEP1).

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is for lent?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lent) indicates your mother is correct. In part it says:

> In the Roman Rite Lent starts on Ash Wednesday and finishes on Holy Saturday. This comprises a period of 46 days. This includes 6 Sundays which are not considered part of Lent because Sundays are days of celebration for Catholics.

You should consult a priest or trusted member of your faith about how this type fast is done. You also  may be wise to inquire of your doctor about your specific situation and if this can be done without impacting your health.